# Configure ports using KafkaClusterTestKit

Tags: apache-kafka

How can we configure a custom port when using `KafkaClusterTestKit` to create an embedded Kafka instance in `kraft` mode? `KafkaClusterTestKit` appears to assign a random port when creating a Kafka instance in `kraft` mode. When creating a server instance in zk mode, we could [assign](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/test/scala/unit/kafka/utils/TestUtils.scala#L300) a custom port. How do we do the same thing using `KafkaClusterTestKit`? Thank you!